# python code for automatic date update

Tags: python

I wrote a code for the date update.
for the original file:

```
12/31/2018  1
12/31/2018  2
12/31/2018  3
12/31/2018  4
12/31/2018  5
12/31/2018  6
12/31/2018  7
12/31/2018  8
12/31/2018  9
12/31/2018  10
12/31/2018  11
12/31/2018  12
12/31/2018  13
12/31/2018  14
12/31/2018  15
12/31/2018  16
12/31/2018  17
12/31/2018  18
12/31/2018  19
12/31/2018  20
12/31/2018  21
12/31/2018  22
12/31/2018  23
12/31/2018  24
12/31/2018  1
12/31/2018  2
12/31/2018  3
12/31/2018  4
12/31/2018  5
12/31/2018  6
12/31/2018  7
```

the first column is date and the second column is time, for the hour become back to 1, I want to have the date to renew.
Here is my code:

```
f_r = open("LMP.csv")
f_w = open("LMP_date.csv","w")
f = csv.reader(f_r)
for line in f:
    [month,day,year] = line[0].split("/")
    if time_ref != 24:
        time_ref = int(line[1])
        f_w.write(str("%04d%02d%02d" % (int(year),int(month),int(day))) + ',' +line[1]+ ',' +line[2]+ ',' +line[3]+'\n')
    else:
        time_ref = int(line[1])
        day = int(day)+1
        leap_year = (int(year)-2000) % 4
        if leap_year != 0:
            if month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:
                if day > 31:
                    day = 1
                    month = int(month)+1
                    if month > 12:
                        month = 1
                        year = int(year)+1
            if month in [4,6,9,11]:
                if day > 30:
                    day = 1
                    month = int(month)+1
            if month in [2]:
                if day > 28:
                    day = 1
                    month = int(month)+1
            f_w.write("%04d%02d%02d" % (int(year),int(month),int(day)) + ',' +line[1]+ ',' +line[2]+ ',' +line[3]+'\n')
        else:
            if month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:
                if day > 31:
                    day = 1
                    month = int(month)+1
                    if month > 12:
                        month = 1
                        year = int(year)+1
            if month in [4,6,9,11]:
                if day > 30:
                    day = 1
                    month = int(month)+1
            if month in [2]:
                if day > 29:
                    day = 1
                    month = int(month)+1
            f_w.write("%04d%02d%02d" % (int(year),int(month),int(day)) + ',' +line[1]+ ',' +line[2]+ ',' +line[3]+'\n')

f_r.close()
f_w.close()
```

however, I have the result as shown below:

```
20181231    1
20181231    2
20181231    3
20181231    4
20181231    5
20181231    6
20181231    7
20181231    8
20181231    9
20181231    10
20181231    11
20181231    12
20181231    13
20181231    14
20181231    15
20181231    16
20181231    17
20181231    18
20181231    19
20181231    20
20181231    21
20181231    22
20181231    23
20181231    24
20181232    1
20181231    2
20181231    3
20181231    4
20181231    5
20181231    6
```

hope someone can help me with this. I actually want:

```
20181231    22
20181231    23
20181231    24
20190101    1
20190101    2
20190101    3
20190101    4
20190101    5
20190101    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping track of the number of days in each month, etc, looks like a whole lot of work. I suggest using the `datetime` module, which will handle all such details for you.

```
import datetime

#iterate through all days between `start` and `end`
def iter_dates(start, end):
    cur_time = start
    while cur_time < end:
        yield cur_time
        cur_time += datetime.timedelta(1)

for date in iter_dates(datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6)):
    for i in range(1, 25):
        print date.strftime("%Y%m%d"), i
```

Result: (some lines clipped out for brevity)

```
20181225 1
20181225 2
20181225 3
20181225 4
...
20181225 23
20181225 24
20181226 1
20181226 2
...
20181231 23
20181231 24
20190101 1
20190101 2
...
20190105 21
20190105 22
20190105 23
20190105 24
```